# remove rows/lines from a file that do not meet a criteria

Tags: bash

How do I remove rows that do not meet a certain criteria from this.

```
$ head -n 50 countries_lat_long_int_code2.csv | tail -n 25
BJ,9.30769,2.315834,Benin,229
BM,32.321384,-64.75737,Bermuda,1
BN,4.535277,114.727669,Brunei
BO,-16.290154,-63.588653,Bolivia,591
BR,-14.235004,-51.92528,Brazil,55
BS,25.03428,-77.39628,Bahamas,1
BT,27.514162,90.433601,Bhutan,975
BV,-54.423199,3.413194,Bouvet Island
BW,-22.328474,24.684866,Botswana,267
BY,53.709807,27.953389,Belarus,375
BZ,17.189877,-88.49765,Belize,501
CA,56.130366,-106.346771,Canada,1
CC,-12.164165,96.870956,Cocos [Keeling] Islands
CD,-4.038333,21.758664,Congo [DRC]
CF,6.611111,20.939444,Central African Republic,236
CG,-0.228021,15.827659,Congo [Republic]
CH,46.818188,8.227512,Switzerland,41
CI,7.539989,-5.54708,Côte d'Ivoire
CK,-21.236736,-159.777671,Cook Islands,682
CL,-35.675147,-71.542969,Chile,56
CM,7.369722,12.354722,Cameroon,237
CN,35.86166,104.195397,China,86
CO,4.570868,-74.297333,Colombia,57
CR,9.748917,-83.753428,Costa Rica,506
CU,21.521757,-77.781167,Cuba,53
```

for instance the following do not have a trailing comma followed by a number at the end of the line

```
BN,4.535277,114.727669,Brunei
BV,-54.423199,3.413194,Bouvet Island
CC,-12.164165,96.870956,Cocos [Keeling] Islands
CD,-4.038333,21.758664,Congo [DRC]
CI,7.539989,-5.54708,Côte d'Ivoire
```

How would i remove these lines or all lines that do not have a trailing comma followed by a number at the end of the line? I am looking to do this in bash, I know I can do it in excel but i would rather do it in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -E ',[0-9]+$' file
BJ,9.30769,2.315834,Benin,229
BM,32.321384,-64.75737,Bermuda,1
BO,-16.290154,-63.588653,Bolivia,591
BR,-14.235004,-51.92528,Brazil,55
BS,25.03428,-77.39628,Bahamas,1
BT,27.514162,90.433601,Bhutan,975
BW,-22.328474,24.684866,Botswana,267
BY,53.709807,27.953389,Belarus,375
BZ,17.189877,-88.49765,Belize,501
CA,56.130366,-106.346771,Canada,1
CF,6.611111,20.939444,Central African Republic,236
CH,46.818188,8.227512,Switzerland,41
CK,-21.236736,-159.777671,Cook Islands,682
CL,-35.675147,-71.542969,Chile,56
CM,7.369722,12.354722,Cameroon,237
CN,35.86166,104.195397,China,86
CO,4.570868,-74.297333,Colombia,57
CR,9.748917,-83.753428,Costa Rica,506
CU,21.521757,-77.781167,Cuba,53
```

Comment: ah so this looks for rows/lines that end in `',[0-9]+$'` as opposed to ones that do not end in `',[0-9]+$'`?

Comment: `head -n 50 countries_lat_long_int_code2.csv | tail -n 25 | grep -vE ',[0-9]+$' | cat -n` using `-v` shows the lines that do not match

Answer (score 0):

Using `cat file | awk '/[,][0-9]+$/'`

Comment: Thanks, I forget the zero.

Comment: can I change this so it does not apply it to the first line?